# Pure version of `std.format.format!`?

Tags: d, function-attributes

I'd like to convert a double to a string in a pure function. I'm confused as to why this isn't pure:

```
wstring fromNumber(double n) pure {
    import std.format;
    return std.format.format!("%s"w)(n);
}
```

Is there a way to implement this function in a `pure` way without having to reimplement the logic for converting a double to a base10 string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so the reason it isn't pure is that the conversion depends on global information like the locale (`1,4` vs `1.4` for example) and the floating point rounding flag in the CPU. the D implementation calls out to a C function which relies on these.. so i kinda think the answer is someone will have to reimplement the logic and that's non-trivial for a lot of reasons.